# Apache2 mistakes with my websites

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2, ocs

I will start with the fact that I have an UBUNTU 16.04 server with OCS Inventory and GLPI, MyPHPadmin, Apache2 etc. on it.
Each computer on which the OCS Agent will be installed will appear in the program database which is at the given address: MY_Adress_IP / ocsreports.

Today I wanted to install OCS plugins but one of the plugins required the installation of the Ngnix package. After refreshing the page, I received the "403 Forbidden" message. I checked Apache2 status. The log displayed an error during the start of the httpd process.

I uninstalled with apt-get purge and apt-get removed ngnix, but this gave a negative result because the address: My_Adress_IP / ocsreport does not work as if the page did not exist.

I reinstalled Apache2. He started, but my site does not work (website OCS, GLPI, Myphpadmin panel)
I will add that OCS, GLPI, PHP, APACHE2, MyPHPadmin is installed on the server.

How to connect or configure the new Apache2 with OCS? Will I have to install OCS from scratch?

I will add that My_Adress_IP / myphpadmin does not work either.

Show databases command; shows that there are bases.

Sorry for my bad language.

Comment: More appropriate for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Can you post relevant output from the apache2 log and error files? It might help.